# F# list spread over multiple lines

Tags: list, f#, syntax-error, line-breaks, lambda

Ok, I have a List of functions in F#, 
and for claritry i want to spread them over multiple lines, 
as shown:

```
type pos=char*int
let potentialPoss:List<pos->pos>=
    [fun (c,i)->(c+char 1,i+2);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char -1,i+2);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char 1,i-2);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char -1,i-2);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char 2,i+1);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char -2,i+1);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char 2,i-1);
    fun (c,i)->(c+char -2,i-2) ]
```

Seems reasonable enough right?
(FYI, pos stores the algebracic position of a chess piece, and potentialPoss is a list of knights moves)

But I get a syntax on the
second **fun** :"*Unexpected keyword 'fun' in expression. Expected ']' or other token.*"
and on the  **[**: "*Unmatched '['.*"

this feels like hte right syntax to me?
any sugestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need all the list elements to be as indented as the first element:

```
[fun (c,i)->(c+char 1,i+2);
 fun (c,i)->(c+char -1,i+2);
 fun (c,i)->(c+char 1,i-2);
 etc
```

This is true for all blocks of code (computation expressions, pattern matching, etc).

Comment: even if the indent it a space rather than a tab, Ok

Comment: @Oxinabox F# doesn't even allow tabs, only spaces. How many of them you indent with is up to you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why the compiler barfs on this, but this fixes it:

```
type pos=char*int
let potentialPoss:List<pos->pos>=
    [
        fun (c,i)->(c+char 1,i+2)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char -1,i+2)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char 1,i-2)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char -1,i-2)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char 2,i+1)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char -2,i+1)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char 2,i-1)
        fun (c,i)->(c+char -2,i-2) 
    ]
```

Incidentally, semicolons are generally interchangeable with line breaks in F#, so I removed them.